# Applications are no longer writing to their log files

Tags: centos, logging

Im not sure what has happened, but im having some trouble with postfix so i went to check the maillog to find it hasnt been written to in days. I checked apache and mysql logs and the same thing is happening. It looks like it happened around the same time for them all.

```
service rsyslog status
```

shows that the application is running, so im not sure what else could be causing this to happen.

Logs were usually being written to /var/log/maillog, var/log/httpd/error_log.

I checked and the folder has 0666 permissions and root is the owner/group.

Is there a global system log where i might be able to find out what is going on?

Im running centos 7. I have tried restarting the entire OS and it had no affect.

```
[root@mail1 log]# ls -l
total 244
-rw------- 1 root  utmp   66048 Nov 22 14:11 btmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root    1808 Nov 22 14:01 cron
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root       0 Nov 22 15:40 dmesg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root       0 Nov 22 14:21 dmesg.old
drwx------ 2 root  root    4096 Nov 22 08:25 httpd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  649116 Nov 22 15:40 lastlog
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   49069 Nov 22 14:20 maillog
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql   4096 Nov 22 08:26 mariadb
-rw------- 1 root  root   18073 Nov 22 15:40 messages
-rw------- 1 root  root   32857 Nov 22 14:20 secure
-rw------- 1 root  root       0 Nov 22 10:38 spooler
-rw------- 1 root  root       0 Nov 22 07:28 tallylog
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root  utmp   19968 Nov 22 15:40 wtmp
-rw------- 1 root  root    3948 Nov 22 10:38 yum.log
```

Hard disk space output

```
[root@mail1 log]# df -m
Filesystem        1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop55386p1    101672  1172     96302   2% /
devtmpfs               4096     0      4096   0% /dev
tmpfs                  4096     0      4096   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  4096     9      4088   1% /run
tmpfs                  4096     0      4096   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Comment: Is your disk full?

Comment: no its not, i have updated the post with the hdd stats. i wiped most of the drive today so its pretty much empty. it was only 49/100gb before i wiped /var/www/html

Comment: You're on an OpenVZ-based VPS. This has many failure modes which are not visible to you, one of which is that you can't see if the disk is full on the host. I'd get rid of it as quickly as possible, for that and many other reasons.

Comment: i can write other things to the disk so it doesnt look like a space issue

Comment: You really need to gather some information what you ave provided isn't much use to us. can read bout debugging rsyslod here http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/troubleshooting/

Comment: I have made some progress, but still an issue. If i run service postfix status -l . i get the end of the log information, but i dont know where this is coming from. rsyslog says its logging to /var/log/maillog, but nothing is happening there